# Can I use Time Machine but still be able to access deleted files on my Mac?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine

Normally I just copy important files on my external HDD or move the big files on there cause I don't have much space on my Mac.

However, I want to try Time Machine, because it might be less prone to HDD failure. Since I recently just got a toasted HDD and now all my important files are lost.

Question is, if I want to just move a big file from my Mac to my external HDD just to free up space on my Mac (I'm always low on local storage), can Time Machine do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move files away from your Mac to an external HDD when using Time Machine.

The file will remain in the backups until the backup drive runs full and Time Machine starts deleting older backups.

Note however that the backup will contain a version of the file from before you’ve moved it to an external HDD. If you want to backup files on your external hard drive with Time Machine, you’ll need to remove the external drive from the list of exclusions in Time Machine settings.

Comment: I's also add a statement e.g.: Files that you do not want to be deleted by Time Machine as the disk fills should be backed up separately.

Comment: Isnt it a bit of a hassle to go all the way back on your backups just to retrieve a file? Also isnt it scary that it might get overwritten with a new backup (with the deleted file)? I heard its not advisable to use the time machine hdd to use it as a normal hdd? Am i better off not using it? Or am i missing out? Cause it seems really helpful in case my mac fails on me

Comment: You do not want to use the same hard drive for both purposes. Use one for storing large files - and another for Time Machine backups of the internal and external drives.

Comment: @user45100, My external drives are much larger then my internal drive and I have been using my Time Machine Backup Drives to also store other files, outside of the `Backups.backupdb` used by it, without issue for over 10 years. Different drives over the years; however, I have not filled up the drive to the point that Time Machine prunes itself.  You can also partition the external drive to isolate non-TM backup files leaving the volume used by TM to be an appropriate size.

Comment: Technically you can definitely store other files besides the Time Machine backup. In practice, you often would not - as those files would then not be backed up by Time Machine.

Comment: @jksoegaard How risky is it to do that? Like what would happen if i store other non-TM files? Would there a need to partition the drive? Cause i dont want to do that and limit the TM storage. The other commenter said hes been doing it for 10 yrs and no problem

Comment: There’s no specific risk in storing the files as such. As mentioned, the risk is that you do not have a backup of such files, so if the drive fails, you loose the data.